# How to disable and enable screenshot in Android while backgrounding the app

Tags: android, screenshot

I want to disable screenshot when my app goes in the background or in-app switcher mode.
Tried below solution but it does not work

```
public override fun onPause() {
   window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE)
   super.onPause()
}

public override fun onResume() {
   super.onResume()
   window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE)
}

I tested on different devices it does not work on few devices like Nokia and Samsung and One plus and worked on MI device and in emulator above API level 24.
```

Comment: please provide some more information on what environment you're using for development

Comment: @M Z Android development

Answer (score 2):

use this code

```
getWindow().setFlags(LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE, LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE);
```

Comment: Tried with same it works on button click or in onCreateView but in onPause and OnResume as mention in the code does not work, as i want to prevent screenshot only in app switcher mode when its in background.

Comment: Set it once, before you call `setContentView`

Comment: @Lennoard Silva i want to prevent screenshot only in app switcher mode when backgrounding the app not when app is in foreground.

Comment: Do you want this code to be applied to all parts of the mobile?

Comment: @ali riahi, Yes

Comment: This works only on the Activity level, so if you want to disable screen capturing for multi-activity applications you would need to apply this setting to each activity.

Answer (score 0):

In API level 33

**setRecentsScreenshotEnabled (boolean enabled)** in onCreate of your main activity.

If set to false, this indicates to the system that it should never take a screenshot of the activity to be used as a representation in recents screen. By default, this value is true.

Answer (score 0):

Pasting my solution in case anybody is interested, as using onPause() and onResume() was not working in all scenarios:

```
import android.view.WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE

override fun onTopResumedActivityChanged(isTopResumedActivity: Boolean) {
    if (isTopResumedActivity.not()) window.setFlags(FLAG_SECURE, FLAG_SECURE)

    super.onTopResumedActivityChanged(isTopResumedActivity)

    if (isTopResumedActivity) window.clearFlags(FLAG_SECURE)
}
```

Tested just on Pixel 6a.